# SQL Order By with 2 Column - Grouping of Sellers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wanted to group sellers with order by price in sql, Let's say I have below table data with me. I want to order by price first, But when seller is exist multple time in table that should be just below.(Means same sellers together).

Table Data

```
 SellerID   SellerName  Price
 88         FlipKart    3950
 32         eBay        4139
 153        Amazon      4139
 96         Walmart     4388
 88         FlipKart    5999
 153        Amazon      4464
```

Requirement :

```
 SellerID   SellerName  Price
 88         FlipKart    3950
 88         FlipKart    5999
 32         eBay        4139
 153        Amazon      4139
 153        Amazon      4464
 96         Walmart     4388
```

Code below is not giving expected result.

```
SELECT SellerID, SellerName, Price 
FROM TableName 
ORDER BY Price, SellerID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use window function `MIN(..) OVER..` to get the lowest price for each `SellerName` and sort by it.

```
SELECT  SellerID,
        SellerName,
        Price
FROM    TableName
ORDER   BY MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY SellerID),
        SellerID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0503/2)

Comment: Hi John, I saw the fiddle and "Amazon" is not grouped. Can you please see again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select *, min(price) over (partition by sellerid order by sellerid) mp
 from tablename),

select sellerid, sellername, price
from cte
order by mp, sellerid
```

Demo [here](http://rextester.com/GCD46462).